# How to config route when a Rails app is behind Apache proxy/reverseproxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

Currently http://www.example.com/ is served by Apache. Some while ago, there is an internal Rails blog app running on:

```
  http://192.168.10.1:3000
```

Now we want to let users access the internal app from the internet, so setup Apache proxy/reverseproxy as:

```
<Location /blog>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  ProxyPass http://192.168.10.1:3000
  ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.10.1:3000
</Location>
```

hoping that users can access the blog app by:

```
  http://www.example.com/blog
```

The problem is, the Rails routes redirected are all wrong, e.g.: `http://www.example.com/blog` requires login, user not logged in are routed to `/login` redirects to:

```
  http://www.example.com/login
```

(which does not exist, and resources such as js and css are not loaded), instead of:

```
  http://www.example.com/blog/login
```

Is there a way config the rails route to handle the above requirement? Or is it simply not possible to proxy a Rails app behind Apache?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the .htaccess proxy approach:

let's take that this is your application `http://192.168.10.1:3000`

create following .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://192.168.10.1:3000/$1 [P]
```

in this example: customer accessing `http://www.example.com/blog/<anything>` link will be proxied to `http://192.168.10.1:3000/<anything>`

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to run

```
ProxyPass /blog http://192.168.10.1:3000
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html